# Why God blessed a deceiver or liar?

Tags: genesis

Jacob was a deceiver/liar (Genesis 27:19-) but here God is supporting a deceiver and blessed him.

Comment: I am voting to close as this opinion based. Here, we are trying to study the meaning of texts, and the various "but this seems wrong to me" questions are best left to a debate on ethics or theology, but have little to do with understanding what the text means.

Comment: Jacob saw that Esau despised the birthright, so Jacob purchased it from him. Having done so, he had the identity and he presented himself in that identity in order to obtain the blessing which Isaac, the lover of venison, would have denied him. Rebekah, to whom God had made a promise, aided Jacob. And you call this 'deception' and 'lying'. But God  blessed Jacob : and God is righteous. -1 and voted for closure.

Comment: Do not delete and repost your closed questions, that is not allowed. Your question has been closed because it doesn't actually ask about the exegesis of a Bible passage. Indeed, Genesis 27 does not say that God supported Jacob in his lies, and he will be judged for them.

Answer (score 3):

The text in question may be given as Genesis 27:19 ff. but the answer comes when other related verses about Isaac are collated. Then a clear picture emerges as to why God blessed Isaac despite what appears, at surface level, to be what we today might take as deceiving and lying. Was it really deceit that secured the blessing? Given the build-up of events, right from the birth of Isaac and his twin brother, Esau, the biblical answer is quite clear and requires no personal opinions.

The explanation starts with Isaac being married for 20 years to Rebekah, yet she remained barren. Isaac pleaded with God that she bear children, God promised she would, and she had twins. The names given to her twins were significant.

The older twin was named Esau because it was a play on his body having red hair. Jacob's name came from 'heel' and 'deceiver' as he was born grasping the heel of his brother, and the 'deceiver' aspect prophetically showed one aspect of his character. Esau's character was 'of the [red] earth', he being a hunter of game. He grew up to be so taken with material things that he sold his birth-right for a meal of red stew. Jacob, however, appreciated the spiritual value of the birth-right and with utter determination obtained it, playing on his brother's weakness. Esau showed contempt for it - which actually was much worse than mere weakness - he despised the things of God. Jacob did not.

Jacob's strong ambition was his weakness, which got him into trouble, danger even, due to not waiting on God's way of fulfilling the previous promises but trying to secure it himself. His mother did likewise, instructing him how to get the birth-right at his father's death-bed. The Lord dealt severely with Jacob, finally purging him of his carnal methods so that ***in his old age God changed his name to Israel (which means 'God fights').***

Isaac realized Jacob had tricked him to get the first-born's birth-right only after he'd blessed Jacob. A time lapse happened before Esau pointed out the trickery. When he begged for a blessing too, Isaac did have one, but because of the covenant nature of such blessings of inheritance, once stated they could not be changed. That pronouncement to Jacob had been an oracle from God, through Isaac's lips, and he knew it.

Bear in mind that the blessing was not false. In Genesis 27:33 Isaac began to tremble uncontrollably at the realization of what had happened, yet he told Esau "That blessing must stand!" That was because the blessing was legal. Isaac knew he had been tampering with God's plan, and God had overruled him. Now Jacob had been made Esau's master! Once the deception was in the open, Isaac then gave Jacob another blessing based on what he now knew God wanted him to do.

But then Jacob had to flee from his enraged older twin brother which is when he fell foul of crafty Laban and got a severe dose of his own medicine. Jacob had met his match with his father-in-law, however, and that's where we see Isaac using his wits again to get ahead. It took most of the rest of his life for God to deal with what was wrong with him - trying to push events on his way instead of learning to wait upon God. The dysfunctional family was eventually sorted out but what grief they caused themselves along the way!

Is this not true time without number in God's dealings with sinful families and individuals? It often takes a life-time of God's patience to change impatient people (like me) so that they eventually see God's hand in affairs they assumed they'd caused earlier on. How grateful they then are for the sovereign grace of God, despite their sinful natures that only he can deal with. Bear in mind that the apostle Peter lied three times on the night of our Lord's betrayal, yet Jesus knew he would, prayed for him and, instructed his later restoration. Likewise, **God blessed Jacob, and his blessing was entirely righteous, in keeping with his foretold promises.**

Comment: Good answer. +1.